# NS2 New AQM implementation

Tags: ns2

I am currently working on NS2 about different queue managers including RED. I am trying to incorporate queue managers not built-in with NS2 like FRED and BLUE. I have been trying several methods and instructions including the ones that can only be found inside the actual research papers of said queue managers. I have also searched here but of no luck. I am getting this error by the way.

```html
invalid command name "Queue/FRED"
    while executing
"Queue/FRED create _o42 "
    invoked from within
"catch "$className create $o $args" msg"
    invoked from within
"if [catch "$className create $o $args" msg] {
if [string match "__FAILED_SHADOW_OBJECT_" $msg] {
delete $o
return ""
}
global errorInfo
error "class $..."
    (procedure "new" line 3)
    invoked from within
"new Queue/$qtype"
    ("default" arm line 3)
    invoked from within
"switch -exact $qtype {
ErrorModule {
if { [llength $args] > 0 } {
set q [eval new $qtype $args]
} else {
set q [new $qtype Fid]
}
}
intserv {
set qtyp..."
    (procedure "_o3" line 14)
    (Simulator simplex-link line 14)
    invoked from within
"_o3 simplex-link _o13 _o16 1Mb 10ms FRED"
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval $self simplex-link $n1 $n2 $bw $delay $type $args"
    (procedure "_o3" line 8)
    (Simulator duplex-link line 8)
    invoked from within
"$ns duplex-link $n1 $n2 1Mb 10ms FRED"
    (file "fred.tcl" line 31)
```

These are a few of the instructions I've tried to add FRED and BLUE but returns the same error.

[Berkeley Instructions](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~istoica/csfq/step-by-step.html) | 
[NS2 instructions](https://sites.google.com/site/engrsanaullahmanzoor/my-resume)

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
Edit: I pasted the error in a snippet to present the error code neatly.

Comment: Please don't link to image sites with screen grabs of your errors, paste the actual error text in your question. 

This allows the question to be searchable and also makes the question future proof in case the image links disappear.

Comment: ? Which ns2 version was used for FRED ? ..... Your errors : No "Queue/FRED" was compiled into the executable 'ns'. ( tcl/lib/[files] ). Or : You are using a wrong copy of 'ns'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example building ns2 + FRED

```
tar xvf ns-allinone-2.34.tar.gz
cd ns-allinone-2.34/
patch -p0 < FRED_ns234.patch
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sriJu2VjvxzT63XAdrohgCppx1nzu5j8/view?usp=sharing

```
export CC=gcc34 CXX=g++34 && ./install
cd ns-2.34/
cp ns ns234-FRED    (This is your backup and safe identifier for ns+FRED)
sudo cp ns234-FRED /usr/local/bin/
```

Simulation : `$ ns234-FRED [simulation].tcl`

---

And ns-2.35 → ns-allinone-2.35_gcc5.tar.gz
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNVVlxR0ZNRGVORjQ/view?usp=sharing

Patch: FRED_ns235.patch https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xnYd0xXV53mLloL1Wjzh_HtGua71jpx5/view?usp=sharing

---

Ubuntu downloads ...

64bits gcc34 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNRTkzQnRSNXZ6UVU/view?usp=sharing ... **g++34** https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNV3J3bnVoWGNWdG8/view?usp=sharing

32bits gcc34 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNTzNKRHBEMHFwNTg/view?usp=sharing ... **g++34** https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNT0JTTVNDSHpNVGM/view?usp=sharing

Install : `$ cd Downloads/ && sudo gdebi [package]_[arch]`

---

Howto FRED, ns-2.35, Ubuntu 16.04

```
tar xvf ns-allinone-2.35_gcc5.tar.gz
cd ns-allinone-2.35/
patch -p0 < FRED_ns235.patch
./install              // Stops with queue/csfq* error.
cd ns-2.35/            // Edit the Makefile line 37 to CPP = g++34
make                   // Stops with linker error (Or earlier)
                       // Edit the Makefile line 37 to CPP = g++
make
cp ns ns235-FRED
sudo cp ns235-FRED /usr/local/bin/
```

Comment: Hi. I'm using ns-2.35 by the way. will try this solution now. thank you so much. and I was just wondering how you compiled these patches?

Comment: Hi again,

I'm having error about not having a file named 'ns' to copy to.
And I have tried re-installing ns2.35 and tried installing ns2.34 in another virtual machine but am still getting the same error posted above. anything I did wrong?

Comment: »»not having a file named 'ns' to copy to«« : Copy **from** 'ns' if it was created at all. .... How to write a patch : `$ diff -Naur ns-2.34-orig/ ns-2.34 >> FRED_ns234.patch`. .... NS-2.34 : Install `gcc34, g++34` . NS-2.35 : compile the failing objects with g++34, link with ~g++~4.8 (Edit `Makefile` twice.) ...... Which 'Linux OS´s' can you use ? ? ...

Comment: There were no errors after the patch command. There were a few after the ./install command. I tried adding lines to ./bashrc that were from ns2 install instructions and ns2 works except for FRED.

no ns folder was created as well as  a simulation.tcl. I tried doing your instruction on both Ubuntu 16.04 32bit and Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit VMs. Thank you

Comment: `.bashrc` text https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_aR4Kpu43x6dYxwTv4mTMsoIGRn8C8Xb/view?usp=sharing .... Ubuntu : You cannot build FRED with no gcc34, **g++34**. I will edit my answer to include links to 32bits and 64bits gcc34, g++34.

Comment: »» no ns folder was created as well as a simulation.tcl «« : No folder will be created, hopefully the executable `ns` will be created. ..... Simulation.tcl : Is for you to write yourself. ( I don't know any simulation.tcl example for FRED.)

Comment: Hi, I think I'm close to solving my problem. If I could have a little more of your time Sir. I'm having this error "[IMG]i64.tinypic.com/s3zqds.jpg[/IMG] I uploaded it as an image to clearly see the error carets. I tried removing the csfq.cc from its folder and csfq.o from the makefile and successfully done until the last command with usr/local/bin but showed a Queue/CSFQ error when trying to run tcl scripts even the ones without CSFQ queue in the script. EDIT-I used gcc49, g++49 btw cause I found out it was what my OS was running with.

Comment: See my edited answer : Howto ... Ubuntu  ( Please remember my comment : `Edit the ns-2.35/Makefile twice.` ... First it is g++, then g++34, and finishes with g++ ! )

Comment: Solved. I missed that part about re-Making ns2 with g++ and g++34. Thank you so much. I believe this will help others very much as well.